# AngularJS functionality fail after given a valule to ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below code ([jsfiddle code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/w6uwtjez/))

```
<div ng-app="app">

   <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
   <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
   <p ng-bind="name"></p>
   <p>{{name}}</p>

</div>
```

this is not working when i use `<div ng-app="app">` but it is working fine when I use `<div ng-app="">` (i.e. when remove the value of `ng-app`)

why is that happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) is documentation of angular.module

*The angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules. All modules (angular core or 3rd party) that should be available to an application must be registered using this mechanism.*

Since app is the new module you have created you need to register it in js as

`angular.module("app", []);`

Now ng-app is used to auto-bootstrap the angular application so if you don't have a name for it you don't need to register thats why `ng-app=" "` works fine but not `ng-app="app"`

Answer (score 4):

You might need to initialise angular module as follows:

```
angular.module("app", []);
```

and it will work all fine!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you need the module `app` when you declare it like

```
<div ng-app="app">
```

You need

```
angular.module('app', [])
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6uwtjez/1/).

Answer to your comment:

*You can specify an AngularJS module to be used as the root module for the application. This module will be loaded into the $injector when the application is bootstrapped. It should contain the application code needed or have dependencies on other modules that will contain the code. See angular.module for more information.*

This is quoted from the ***[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)***.

Comment: any reason why it need to be like that and why it's working fine when `ng-app = ""` ?

Comment: ng-app is the default directive which angular provides. Syntax is <body ng-app></body>. It works

Answer (score 2):

When you write ng-app="app", it will search for a module with the name app. You need to initialise the module as angular.module('app', []) - then only it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Whenver you writing `<body ng-app="myApp">` which means you are providing value to directive and angular always use to find values with directive .
And if you have provided value with module which means you have to inject it.
using

```
angular.module('app',[]);
```

'[]' square brackets always contains dependencies ,if your application depends upon anyother angular application then you can inject its dependency here
Follow Docs for more info:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp